# Explanation of a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

Explain NSMutableArray.

Could you reset it after all the deletions to put it back to its original state with all the initial variables?

Comment: Are you after the difference between an NSArray and NSMutableArray or a complete explanation of an array in general?

Comment: No like could you reset it after all the deletions to put it back to its original state with all the initial variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

The main diff between NSArray and NSMutableArray is that NSMutableArray supports insertion and deletion at runtime.

Comment: Can you reset a mutable array then when your finished with it?

Comment: s...u can do it using [mutArray removeAllObjects];

Comment: No like could you reset it after all the deletions to put it back to its original state with all the initial variables?

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same as NSArray except for being mutable, or to quote official docs

> This class adds **insertion** and **deletion**
>   operations to the basic array-handling
>   behavior inherited from NSArray.

Comment: No like could you reset it after all the deletions to put it back to its original state with all the initial variables?